# ArcGIS Attribute table appears empty until features are selected

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, symbology, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I have a multiple layers that show features in the data frame and the layers are editable and labeled, but when you open the attribute table for these layers, it's empty.  The only way to get the features to appear in the attribute table is to select them.  I have also noticed that these layers have no symbology in the table of contents.  Once again, they have symbology in the data frame just not in the TOC, and I cannot change the symbology anywhere to make it appear in the TOC.  What's going on here?

Comment: I've resolved my issue with the attribute table but not the lack of symbology in the TOC.

Comment: What was the solution for the attribute table?

Comment: It must have been a Arc hiccup because I toggled the show all records tab on the bottom left and then all attributes appeared.  For some reason Arc must have been stuck on show selected records even though it was set to show all records.

Comment: Strange. Can you provide us with a screenshot of your TOC?

Answer (score 2):

In the TOC, make sure you are in "List By Drawing Order/Source/Visibility" mode (rather than by Selection), and of course make sure the expand/collapse icon to the left of the layer is showing a minus sign, meaning it is expanded to show the symbology, as in the following screenshot:

[image: List By Drawing Order]

In the attribute table, make sure you are in "Show all records" (rather than "Show selected records") mode, as in the following screenshot:

[image: Show all records]

Comment: Thank you for your feedback but these are not causing the issues that I am facing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Data- Data Export to create a new feature class? The Attribute table populated after doing this for me.